# Setting Cookie in Laravel Custom Middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I want to set a cookie in a custom Laravel middleware. The idea is to set the cookie value any time a user visits my website through any landing page.

So what I did was I created a middleware named `UUIDMiddleware`. I am using this middleware along with web middleware in my routes. Below is its code from the middleware.

```php
if($request->hasCookie('uuid'))
{
    return $next($request);    
}
else
{
    $uuid = Uuid::generate();
    $response = new Response();
    return $response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('uuid', $uuid));
}
```

As you can see I am checking if cookie exists. If not, I am passing control to next request.

The problem is when setting a cookie using `return $response`, I cannot pass control to next request. How do I resolve this?

What happens in this case is if a cookie is not set, it sets a cookie and a blank screen shows up. If I refresh, I see the website with a cookie set.

There has to be a way to set cookie using middleware in the right way. How do I do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The response object in [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware) is returned by the `$next` closure, so you could do something like this:

```php
if($request->hasCookie('uuid')) {
    return $next($request);    
}

$uuid = Uuid::generate();
return $next($request)
    ->withCookie(cookie()->forever('uuid', $uuid));
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. Calling `$next($request)` regardless of whether you are returning it or not breaks out of the handle method and continues the request.

Comment: @Chris This isn't true (at least for Laravel 5.4). Are you sure you registered the middleware?

Comment: @Boyd the middleware was registered. What I had to do in the end was return $next($request)->withCookie() and supply my cookie object. It actually seems like the cookie is not being carried unless explicitly defined

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of this answer was (or why it garnered 16 upvotes) since it just repeated the code that was in the question. I've edited it to provide a working solution.

Comment: It's not the same code though... And you just refactored the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Laravel 5.8 and like me you want a solution that allows you set the expiration time of the cookie instead of setting it to forever, you could also do something like this in the [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $time = time() + 60 * 60 * 24; //One day
    $res = $next($request);
    return $res->cookie('cookie_name', $cookieValue, $time, "/");
}
```

This would set the cookie when the controller is done with the request and is returning a response.